# Entity Framework db updated but browser dosent show

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net-mvc

I am thying to "add new Customer" in function "AddOrEdit", when I press submit I cant see the entity in the browser, but the db is updated.
that problem happend only since I changed the GetData function I added the FilmName to the table of customers and since then this problem happens.

```
              @{
        ViewBag.Title = "Index";
           }
          <a class="btn btn-primary" style="margin-bottom:10px" 
            onclick="PopupForm('@Url.Action("AddOrEdit","Customers")')"><i class="fa 
           fa-plus"></i> New Customer</a>

              <h2>Customers</h2>

           <div style="width:90%; margin:0 auto;">
        <table id="myTable">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Customer Name</th>
                    <th>Phone</th>
                    <th>Film Id</th>
                    <th>Film Name</th>
                    <th></th>

                </tr>
            </thead>
        </table>
    </div>
    <style>
        tr.even {
            background-color: #F5F5F5;
        }
    </style>


    @* Load datatable css *@
    <link href="//cdn.datatables.net/1.10.9/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    @* Load datatable js *@
    @section Scripts{
        <script src="//cdn.datatables.net/1.10.9/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.15/js/dataTables.bootstrap.min.js"></script>

        <script>
            var Popup, dataTable;
            $(document).ready(function () {
                dataTable= $('#myTable').DataTable({
                    "ajax": {
                        "url": "/Customers/GetData/GetData",
                        "type": "GET",
                        "datatype": "json"
                    },
                    "columns" : [
                           { "data": "CustomerName", "autoWidth": true },
                            { "data": "Phone", "autoWidth": true },
                            { "data": "FilmId", "autoWidth": true },
                            { "data": "FilmName", "autoWidth": true },
                            {"data":"CustomerId" , "render" : function (data) {
                            return "<a class='btn btn-default btn-sm' 
                        onclick=PopupForm('@Url.Action("AddOrEdit","Customers")/" + 
                       data + "')><i class='fa fa-pencil'></i> Edit</a><a class='btn 
                   btn-danger btn-sm' style='margin-left:5px' 
                    onclick=Delete("+data+")><i class='fa fa-trash'></i> Delete</a>";
                            },
                                "orderable": false,
                                "searchable": false,
                                "width": "150px"
                            }

                    ],
                    "language": {

                        "emptyTable": "No data found, Please click on <b>Add New</b> 
               Button"
                    }
                });
            });

            function PopupForm(url) {
                var formDiv = $('<div/>');
                $.get(url)
                .done(function (response) {
                    formDiv.html(response);

                    Popup = formDiv.dialog({
                        autoOpen: true,
                        resizable: false,
                        title: 'Fill Customer Details',
                        height: 500,
                        width: 700,
                        close: function () {
                            Popup.dialog('destroy').remove();
                        }

                    });
                });
            }
            function SubmitForm(form) {
                $.validator.unobtrusive.parse(form);
                if($(form).valid()){
                    $.ajax({
                        type : "POST",
                        url : form.action,
                        data : $(form).serialize(),
                        success : function (data) {
                            if(data.success)
                            {
                                Popup.dialog('close');
                                dataTable.ajax.reload();

                                $.notify(data.message,{
                                    globalPosition :"top center",
                                    className : "success"
                                })

                            }
                        }
                    });
                }
                return false;
            }

            function Delete(id) {
                if(confirm('Are You Sure to Delete this Employee Record ?'))
                {
                    $.ajax({
                        type: "POST",
                        url: '@Url.Action("Delete","Customers")/' + id,
                        success: function (data) {
                            if (data.success)
                            {
                                dataTable.ajax.reload();

                                $.notify(data.message, {
                                    globalPosition: "top center",
                                    className: "success"
                                })

                            }
                        }

                    });
                }
            }
        </script>
    }
```

here is the CustomerController:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using MoviePro.Models;
using System.Data.Entity;

namespace MoviePro.Controllers
{
    public class CustomersController : Controller
    {
        // GET: Customers
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            return View();
        }
        public ActionResult GetData()
        {
            MyDatabaseEntities2 db = new MyDatabaseEntities2();
            var q = (from c in db.Customers
                     from Films in c.Films
                     where Films.FilmId == Films.FilmId
                     where c.CustomerId == c.CustomerId
                     select new
                     {
                         c.CustomerName,
                         c.Phone,
                         c.FilmId,
                         c.CustomerId,
                         //FilmName = Films.FilmName

                     }).ToList();
            return Json(new { data = q }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }

        public ActionResult loaddata()
        {
            MyDatabaseEntities2 dc = new MyDatabaseEntities2();

            var customers = dc.Customers.Select(c => new
            {
                c.CustomerName,
                c.Phone,
                c.FilmId,
                c.CustomerId,


            });

            return Json(new { data = customers }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);

        }

        public ActionResult AddOrEdit(int id = 0)
        {
            if (id == 0)
                return View(new Customers());

            else
            {
                using (MyDatabaseEntities2 db = new MyDatabaseEntities2())
                {
                    return View(db.Customers.Where(x => x.CustomerId== id).FirstOrDefault<Customers>());

                }
            }
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult AddOrEdit(Customers customer)
        {
            using (MyDatabaseEntities2 db = new MyDatabaseEntities2())
            {
                if (customer.CustomerId == 0)
                { 
                    db.Customers.Add(customer);
                    db.SaveChanges();
                    return Json(new { success = true, message = "Saved Successfully" }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
                }
                else
                {
                    db.Entry(customer).State = EntityState.Modified;
                    db.SaveChanges();
                    return Json(new { success = true, message = "Updated Successfully" }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
                }
            }

        }

        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Delete(int id)
        {
            using (MyDatabaseEntities2 db = new MyDatabaseEntities2())
            {
                Customers emp = db.Customers.Where(x => x.CustomerId == id).FirstOrDefault<Customers>();

                db.Customers.Remove(emp);
                db.SaveChanges();
                return Json(new { success = true, message = "Deleted Successfully" }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: what is exactly your problem ?

Comment: the problem is that I cant see the new customer in the table, but in the db it is added

Answer (score 0):

I think your ajax request's url is wrong.

```
"ajax": {
           "url": "/Customers/GetData/GetData",
           "type": "GET",
           "datatype": "json"
        }
```

You should change it to

```
"url": "/Customers/GetData"
```

Comment: thanks, I changed it, but still cant see the new entity in the table, only at the db

Comment: I think there is more than one mistake. I will check it.